# Maximum PATA hard drive capacity for an old HP OmniBook vt6200 laptop

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd, compatibility, pata

I’ve been searching for any clue that could tell me if [this HP OmniBook vt6200 laptop](http://www.cnet.com/products/hp-omnibook-vt6200-15-1-p4-m-win-xp-pro-512-mb-ram-30-gb-hdd-series/specs/) has any limitations on the maximum hard drive capacity it supports. But found nothing.

It’s a laptop from around 2002. It currently has a 32GB SSD (PATA interface).

Is there a way to know in advance if this laptop supports anything bigger than 32GB?

Comment: In addition... well... Its a PIV. There's a reasonable chance that unless there's a specific feature on the system that you need (serial or parallel ports?) replacing the system might pay for itself in terms of power consumption and speed within a year or two. A nearly contemporary Pentium M a lower clockspeed would run circles around it , as would a modern bay trail processor. Might be worth considering putting the old warhorse out to pasture.

Answer (score 0):

You're unlikely to be able to find a new pata/laptop IDE drive so I wouldn't be suprised if your limitation is the size of the drive you can get rather than anything else. They simply won't make em any more.

[Considering the limits for older systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA#x86_BIOS_size_limitations) were in terms of hundreds of gigabytes (128 GiB initially, then 128 PiB for ATA 6), that wouldn't really be an issue.

I know the transition between PATA and SATA happened around the 30gb size mark. So whoever upgraded it probably just picked a similar size drive to be sure.

That said, your SSD's probably likely to be a better idea as far as performance goes, and you'd be getting a new/old stock drive anyway. I'd consider increasing storage other ways. An external HDD might be a simpler option, even if you're stuck with USB 1.1 interfaces.

Comment: Unlikely to find? There are [plenty of 64GB PATA SSDs in ebay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_nkw=ssd+2.5+pata+64gb).

Comment: 64 GB is still within the 128GiB size limit for older oses. I was thinking more in the 100s of GiB